# Numbering table caption in Appendix (style based on Heading 1)

Tags: ms-word, word-field

For an appendix in Word I've created a separate style "Appendix 1", based on Heading 1 because it has to show in the right order in the navigation pane. The appendix chapter is numbered using characters: A, B etc.

In the table caption I use a `StyleRef` field to "Appendix 1" in order to show the character "number" of the chapter. So far so good. For the numbering I used an `SEQ` field.

But ... there is my problem: the table caption doesn't restart at 1 at the beginning of a new appendix chapter. It continues the numbering.

The fieldcode switches `\r` or `\r1` do reset, but I want to automate it with a button in the Ribbon to insert the table caption as an autotext. The \r is only necessary for the first table caption in the chapter. And what if the user decides to insert a table before the first table afterwards?

I can't figure out how to solve this. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this? Thank you in advance.

I've googled for this problem and every solution for numbering the appendices says that I have to use Heading 6 or 7. But then it doesn't show up correctly in the navigation pane.

I used this to get the result Table A.1, Table A.2 etc.

```
Table {STYLEREF "Appendix 1" \s} {SEQ AppendixTable \* ARABIC \s "Appendix 1"}
```

Problem: First table in Appendix B = Table B.3 but has to be B.1

I would like the table caption to restart at 1 every time a new chapter begins.

Comment: Hi & welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to add some pictures, and generally make your post fancier. That'll help to get people interested in your issue

Comment: "Generally make your post fancier" doesn't tell the OP anything about how to truly improve the question... @Cukic0d

Comment: Given the requirements, the only possibility that occurs to me is to use a different SEQ field for each chapter. AppendixATable, AppendixBTable, etc. Which would mean multiple AutoText entries and maybe a dropdown control in the Ribbon. That, or you'd need to resort to using code...

Comment: Hm I'll try that if it's the only option. Of course in a dropdown in the ribbon, to make it a bit more user friendly. Thank you Cindy.